# calculating cosine similarity using MapReduce

Tags: mapreduce, recommendation-engine, cosine-similarity

I am trying making a item-based recommendation using cosine similarity with MapReduce.

Here's the input set.

```
itemIdx_1, userIdx_1
itemIdx_1, userIdx_2
itemIdx_2, userIdx_1
itemIdx_3, userIdx_3
...
```

How do I design with this input data?

To use cosine similarity, I guess the input should be like below,

```
(no preferences, so data'd be 0 or 1 assumedly)
    itemIdx_1 , [userIdx_1:1, userIdx_2:1, userIdx_3:0]
    itemIdx_2 , [userIdx_1:0, userIdx_2:1, userIdx_3:0]
    ItemIdx_3 , [userIdx_1:0, userIdx_2:0, userIdx_3:1]
    ...
```

But How do I compare each row using MapReduce?

Please help. I've been sick of this for like a week..

Answer (score 0):

item1 means a item and we can use vector [user1,user2,user3... userN] to identify it. And the cosine similarity of item1 and item2 is

```
sum(item1*item2)/ sqrt(sum(item1*item1))* sqrt(sum(item2*item2))
```

You can add this sqrt(sum(item1*item1)) to item1 row; I add it to item row
as D.
NOTE: vector item is sparse.

And I use three steps to do this:

1. Calculate the `sqrt(sum(item*item))` for each item.
2. Map by userid. In this way we get each user`s choice (and the same choice is in the same reduce function). E.g.

   ```
   userid    itemid     rating  (D) 
   223  2344 4
   223  2324 5
   223  3444 3
   ```

   Then combine every two items for each user. Then we get a list of a user`s every two items. E.g.

   ```
   itemid1 itemid2  rating1 rating2 (D1) (D2)  
   2344  2324 4 5  
   ........
   ```
3. (very easy) Calculate itemid1 and itemid2's rating; use `sum(item1*item2)` and we have known `sqrt(sum(item1*item1))` and `sqrt(sum(item2*item2))`, so we get the cosine similarity.